# Formatting of other special functions

Tags: math-mode, symbols, formatting

There are special macros for stuff like exp, sin, cos, etc... but not for the non-elementary special functions like F, J, I, K, E etc... although their symbold are quite standard throughout literature.

I know [ISO/IEC 80000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_80000) standardized the use of mathematical constants as upright, along with greek letters and mathematical operators. I try to adhere to this, because frankly, it looks nicer overall.

Is there a similar standard for the math functions? Would it look weird if I made these upright as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard, that covers all math functions. Some functions are written in a different way, but even than there are several ways to do this. For example the indicator function can be written with a

- bold 1:
- double struck 1:
- bold, upright I:
- double struck, upright I:
- italic I:

I don't know about ISO, but the German standard, DIN1302, defines the Heaviside function as either  or ε and rect(x), tri(x), sinc(x) and inv(x) in upright math.